# Wall is ripping after tv mount

Tags: mounting, television

We mounted our tv last night and now today there are 2 places where like the wall is cracking. Should we be concerned. We mounted to the studs.

[image]

Comment: Need pictures of the mount and how it was attached to the wall to make any educated suggestions.

Comment: Is this the wall on the other side of where the TV is mounted?

Comment: What are we looking at here? It doesn't seem related to a TV mount.

Answer (score 7):

That photo is pretty close up but I am almost completely sure that those cracks are screw pops that were caused by your TV mount sandwiching the drywall and pulling it a little closer to the studs than it originally was.

When the house is being built, drywall hangers usually go as fast as possible and generally not every stud is perfectly plumb either.  That sometimes leads to small gaps behind the drywall that manifest later as popped screws.  Same thing has happened to me almost every time I mount a TV.

If the cracked areas are around dime to quarter sized and located along studs, I would almost guarantee that that's what they are.

Nothing to worry about - your TV isn't going to fall down as long as you got it into studs.

Comment: A strong magnet can verify that is a screw or nail pop - the magnet will stick to the screw through the drywall coatings.